# Mimic Autologin via ssh (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ssh, login, remote

I want to be able to start a gnome session and login on a pc so it's ready to use when I get to it. Similar to an autologin. But I want to avoid Autologin.

It's a home automation project. At a set time/conditions, the pc is powered up. But when I want to use it, I'll send it a command via ssh (triggered by a voice command) to login and have it ready for use when I get there.

It's the actual ssh command I'm after.

Appreciate anyone's help

Thanks

Comment: Some solutions depend on your displaymanager (gdm3, lightdm, xdm, ...), but might not work with all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for sure not the perfect solution, but it works for `gdm3` which I tested successfully. I am sure the idea can be used as a starting point and can be adapted to other configurations.

**GDM3**

First configure a username which will login, but autologin disabled.

```
git config --file=/etc/gdm3/custom.conf --add daemon.AutomaticLoginEnable false
git config --file=/etc/gdm3/custom.conf --add daemon.AutomaticLogin username
```

Now you can easily autologin via ssh:

```
ssh root@yourhost 'bash -c "git config --file=/etc/gdm3/custom.conf --replace-all daemon.AutomaticLoginEnable true && systemctl restart gdm3 && git config --file=/etc/gdm3/custom.conf --replace-all daemon.AutomaticLoginEnable false"'
```

Be aware, with this "brute-force" solution, any user logged in through `gdm3` will be logged out without notice. You have extend this if you need it.

**Additional Comments**

I know, you said "Without Autologin", but this is somehow not really "Autologin" in common way.

Additionally I can give some (untested) ideas for doing this without autologin and without root login:

Disable graphical login:
`systemctl set-default  multi-user.target`

Use SSH so login to your host and start the graphical interface manually (`startx` ??).

Comment: Thanks Marco. I'll try it out. Will "--add" just keep adding lines to the config file?

Comment: Sorry, cut&paste failure. I updated the answer. `git config` is just an easy way to manipulate such kind of config files. `crudini` would be another possibility.

Comment: Thanks Marco. Does exactly what I need.